# Usar include ou constantes para pegar códigos?

Tags: php, programação-funcional

Criei um arquivo contendo padrões que são usados no meu sistema. Gostaria de saber qual e a diferença em **desempenho** entre chamar o código por um `include` ou por uma `constante` assim:

```php
//código do incluir.php: <a href=""></a>

include "incluir.php";
```

```php
define('_CONSTANT','<a href=""></a>');
```

Tem alguma vantagem em usar um e outro?

Eu pergunto isso pois fico em dúvida se eu utilizar um ou outro pode afetar o desempenho do meu sistema, já que eu uso bastante isso para pegar códigos padrões

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pergunta é bem objetiva sobre qual dos dois é mais performático. Portanto, não comentarei sobre conceitos ou estrutura de dados (mvc, oop, etc) e nem mesmo boas práticas de programação.

Respondendo de forma objetiva, dentro do seu contexto, é mais rápido definindo por constantes. Simples assim.

O motivo é óbvio. O processo de incluir um arquivo consome memória e tempo de execução para carregar um mesmo valor que estaria numa constante. Então, se pode usar as constantes, use-as.